# Парсинг дочерних ссылок с помощью Jsoup

Tags: android, java, jsoup

Столкнулся с таким вопросом: с помощью JSOUP пропарсил главную страницу сайта. Все ссылки занес в `ArrayList<String>`. Далее хочу пропарсить эти ссылки, но не получается их инициализировать.
Код для главной страницы :

```
protected String doInBackground(String... arg) {
        try {
            Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://site.com/archive/").get();
            link = doc.select("a[href]");
            for (Element links : link) 
            {

                LinkList.add(links.attr("abs:href"));
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Для дочерней :

```
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            //for (int i = 0; i < LinkList.size(); i++) {
            //url = url.toLowerCase();
            //if( !LinkList.contains(url) ){
            Document doc1 = Jsoup.connect(url[0]).get();
            Elements img = doc1.select("#strip");
            String imgSrc = img.attr("src");
            InputStream input = new java.net.URL(imgSrc).openStream();
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
            //}
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
        }
```

Пробовал приводить `ArrayList` к простому массиву, но без толку:

```
public ArrayList<String> LinkList = new ArrayList<String>();
String[] url = LinkList.toArray(new String[LinkList.size()]);
```

Идея проста: брать по очереди ссылки из динамического массива и проверять на теги, вот только не выходит. Буду благодарен любым подсказкам.

Рабочий код:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
            Elements links = doc.select("a[href]");
            String link_addr = links.get(3).attr("abs:href");
            Document link_doc = Jsoup.connect(link_addr).get();

            Elements img = link_doc.select("#strip");
            String imgSrc = img.attr("src");
            InputStream input = new java.net.URL(imgSrc).openStream();
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
```

Comment: Привет, делал подобное только я использовал несколько списков, вот мой [git](https://bitbucket.org/KonstantinPetrenko/parsehtml/src/fc0d94cb2a8b673ef212f0ee9b9fb23bc9b5f3cf/app/src/main/java/test/ex/u/parsehtml/?at=master)

Answer (score 2):

Проверяли что у вас находится в `LinkList` после парсинга? Возможно надо изменить

```
LinkList.add(links.attr("abs:href"));
```

на

```
LinkList.add(links.attr("href"));
```

Comment: При такой замене выводит не http://site.com/link1/ а /link1/
`linkList.get(0)` успешно показывает 1ую ссылку